# Using DOM Event Handlers with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a website I am working on that takes input from the user and calculates a results.  All of the forms are html text input forms where they enter in certain number.

I want to use the input event to check for when the user enters a new value in one of these 6 text forms.  The example in the book I am using, [JavaScript and JQuery: Interactive Front-End Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118531647), suggest to use the getElementById method with the dom event handler to do this:

For example:

```
function doWhatIwantToDo()
{
    //Do something
}

var el = document.getElementById('username');
el.oninput = doWhatIwantToDo;
```

This is great and I could set up 6 unique ids for each text form, which I will need to do anyway in order to change their inner html in my javascript code, but is there someway I can check for input by using a class name?

I tried using getElementsByClassName but it is tripping me up because it returns an array of objects.

I want to avoid any jquery solutions right now because I am trying to learn vanilla javascript only right now.

Edit/Results:

I like "acbabis" and "mohamedrias" answers but the book implies that using Event Listeners is a newer method and not supported by all browsers.  So for now, I would like to stick with the Traditional Dom Event Handlers that it talks about.

"dandavis" answer to just do it in a loop made me realize that perhaps binding an element to an event handler, in a loop, SHOULD actually work and that perhaps I was making a mistake in my loop.

I checked and stupidly I wasn't using array notation to loop through each object in the returned array which is why nothing was happening.  Here is my final code that works:

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

for (var i=0; i < test.length; i++)
{
    console.log( test[i] );
    test[i].onclick = testiness;
}

function testiness ()
{
    alert("Success!");
}
```

Comment: just do your last line in a loop of getElementsByClassName()'s result, or, use delegation by inspecting _e.target_ in the event handler and binding to a common location, like <body>

Comment: Can you add that an answer?  Your comment got me thinking and I realized why my attempt at looping through the results didn't work.  That way I can select your answer as the answer.

Comment: just accept mohamedrias's then, it's the same as my comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would `document.querySelectorAll` for this.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('input', doWhatIWantToDo);
}
```

This will find all input elements on the page and add the handler to each one. If you want to use a class, just add it to the desired input tags, and replace `document.querySelectorAll('input')` with `document.querySelectorAll('input.classname')`.

Comment: is querySelector a part of Jquery?

Comment: Nevermind.  Found it in my book.  Looks like it is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('.className');
for(var i = 0, len = inputElements.length ; i < len ; i++) {
    inputElements[i].addEventListener('input', doSomethingFunction);
}
```

`querySelectorAll` returns you a static NodeList. You need to iterate and attach the event.

Instead of using `getElementsByClassName` which returns a live HTMLCollection, working with `querySelectorAll` would be preferrable.

Comment: how would live vs static matter in a single-thread environment when the loop is right after the collection-gathering call?

Comment: if the OP is adding input elements dynamically then the loop can go forever. Just being cautious about that so I prefer using static nodelist.

Comment: hmm, i guess so, didn't consider that. (not that the OP is adding elements anyway) i use [].forEach instead of loops, so i guess i've never had that problem, even when adding inputs. i also cache the length of dom collections when i do use a loop, since it's much faster, and that also would prevent "infinite loops"...

Comment: Yup, if we're caching the length of elements then its cool and it improves performance as you mentioned :) Included your suggestion in answer :)

Comment: is querySelectorAll a part of Jquery?

Comment: Nevermind.  Found it in my book.  Looks like it is not.